# Launching Servlet on Eclipse/Tomcat opens the wrong URL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Everytime I click on `Run on Server` it builds my servlet and opens the browser, but with the wrong URL. The URL called is

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/
```

but this leads to an error 404, because the correct URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/
```

case-sensitive.

The context root is set to `MyProject`. I stopped the server, cleared the tomcat workdirectory and published it several times, but Eclipse still calls the lower-cased URL. Also tried switching the tomcat location from `[workspace metadata]` but this doesn't helped either.

**EDIT:** Using `Eclispe Luna 4.4.0`, `Tomcat v7.0`, `Vaadin 7.4.0` and `Maven`

Comment: Did you check your <servlet-mapping> in web.xml?

Comment: I'm using Vaadin and Maven, and it seems like Vaadin doesn't need a `web.xml` file anymore, therefore it doesn't exists in my project. Where is the right location do create such file or are there other spots I've might missed?

Comment: Has your servlet the WebServlet and VaadinServletConfiguration annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Check your project's properties. There should be an entry for "Web App" or similar where you can specify the context URL.

If you can't find it, search for `myproject` in the folder `.settings` of your project.

Comment: No luck finding it. There are various files in the `.settings` but none of them contains an `myproject` string at all. But this lead me to another idea, I found `workspace\Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config\server.xml` which contains following line: `<Context docBase="MyProject" path="/MyProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject"/>` and if I change the attribute `path`, eclipse opens up the edited url, but still lowercased.

Comment: I don't see why Eclipse would convert the case of the URL. Can you check the launch configuration? Maybe it made a copy there.